# Android development on Win 7 64-bit with Pulse Mini (Huawei)

Tags: android, adb, drivers

Any ideas where I can begin to find out what's going wrong?

I have a T-Mobile Pulse Mini (Huawei) which I'd like to get working for developing and testing apps on.  I can't get it to be seen by Android Debug Bridge despite restarting the adb server.  (and emulators are seen by adb any way so that's unlikely to be the problem).

In the device manager the phone is displayed as a CD-ROM and when I select 'transfer files' from the auto 'PcOptions.exe' it is then displayed as a USB driver but in either case I can't see it in adb.  I have enabled debugging on the phone.  I remember it took me ages to get it to work on my previous Vista 32-bit.  I can't figure out where to search from here.  The drivers used to install the phone are on the phone itself.

Thanks very much.

Comment: Somewhat related: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/23484/is-is-possible-to-make-a-non-rooted-huawei-u8110-t-mobile-pulse-mini-recognisa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drivers. If you can't see the phone in ADB, it's almost always a driver issue and this is especially common on Windows. The regular user drivers are sometimes different from the ADB drivers. If you can find the OEM dev drivers directly that's ideal, otherwise there's a way to modify the INF file which you'll have to Google for unless someone else provides it, as I don't remember the details at the moment.

Comment: Thanks.  I've started searching for "u8110 oem driver" as "pulse mini oem driver" returns this page as 3rd result :P  Will post back with what I find.

Comment: okay I've found:  http://www.huaweidevice.com/worldwide/technicaIndex.do?method=gotoProductSupport&productId=3214&tb=0

Comment: In the huawei_kernel 'kernel\drivers\usb'  there are c and c-header files which if you know what you're doing, I guess you can compile, but these are for the phone itself and not for the Win7 x64 side right?  Any pointers on what I'd need to do to the .inf files from the standard device drivers would be appreciated as I've failed to find any updated drivers.  Or maybe they installed wrong?  Other than format my computer is there a way of making sure they'll all removed and just try again?  The standard driver installer also pauses for a long time at 80%, maybe it's failing to install properly?

Comment: Tried installing the drivers on a Win7 32-bit and again it says the drivers don't install correctly leaving the phone showing up as a CD driver called 'T-Mobile 3G Phone USB Device'

Comment: How about for mac? I've no windows pc.

Comment: Yes, I've tried on 2 diffrent macs and one windows8 pc. Couldn't manage to use it. By the way when I connect it to Mac, OsX gives me alert and says "this disk cannot be read by this computer" Phone's screen is broken. I can barely see it. I need to use remote screen. Debug mode on. :)